# Another prefix suffix puzzle

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

My start is teasing someone,
My infix is a time unit, which means a lot of years ago, but without the y.
My end is Peter Senerchia.
My whole means dazzle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefix

> razz = "Tease someone playfully"

Infix

> ma = "mya (million years ago) without the y"

Suffix

> Tazz = ring name of Peter Senerchia

Whole word

> razzmatazz = "Excited action or impressive display" (the noun meaning of dazzle)